# Debug Actions in VSCode: Meaning

Tags: visual-studio-code

My first 'real' debugging experience has been with VSCode.

I'm trying to learn how to debug in VSCode.

In this [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging), nothing is said about what each debug action does... So, far I haven't had any trouble understanding the Continue / Pause, Step Into, Restart and Stop.

What I don't understand is what Step Over, and Step Out do. There's nothing on it, in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read up in the doc of [Visual Studio Debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2022).

You can create an [issue for the VSC Documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/issues) to explain this or put a link to a page explaining.